# implicit conversion not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I have written a simple `Flags` class, but face a problem with my operator definition. It seems like I'm relying on some nonexistent implicit conversion rule.

```
enum class SomeEnum { ONE, TWO, THREE };

template<typename Enum>
class Flags {
    Flags(const Flags& f) { };
    Flags(Enum e) { };

    Flags& operator |=(Flags<Enum> f) {
        //...;
        return *this;
    }
};

template<typename Enum>
Flags<Enum> operator |(Enum a, Flags<Enum> b) { return b | a; }

template<typename Enum>
Flags<Enum> operator |(Flags<Enum> a, Enum b) { return a |= b; }

int main() {
    Flags<SomeEnum> flags = SomeEnum::ONE | SomeEnum::TWO;
    return 0;
}
```

While compilation I get this error:

```
implicit.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:  
implicit.cpp:26:40: error: no match for ‘operator|’ (operand types are ‘SomeEnum’ and ‘SomeEnum’)  
  Flags<SomeEnum> flags = SomeEnum::ONE | SomeEnum::TWO;
```

My understanding was, that one of the `SomeEnum`s is implicitly converted into a `Flags<Enum>`, and then passed to the correct operator. What rule am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have looked at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593`, but the proposed solution (nonmember-friend operator) did not solve my problem.
I did remove the global definitions and add these members:

```
friend Flags operator |(Enum a, Flags b) { return b | a; }
friend Flags operator |(Flags a, Enum b) { return a |= b; }
```

But the error is still the same ([live demo](https://ideone.com/Wy3Rh3)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ implicit type conversion with template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787593/c-implicit-type-conversion-with-template)

Comment: I am unsure if it is exact duplicate or not (would like someone else to look at it as well), but related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578638/how-to-use-c11-enum-class-for-flags

Comment: I didn't know what exactly to search for, as googling for `implicit conversion does not work as expected` didn't give any good results (obviously)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I don't see anything in common with that question. He has another problem with a `Flags` class (which is not even templated; and he uses operator | with the same type for a and b)

Comment: @nyronium Yet, judging from the error you get - your templated class doesn't even come into question. The error comes for compiler not finding a suitable match for `operator|` where both operands are of type `SomeEnum`, hence - my suggestion.

Comment: @Corristo I have looked at it and edited my question accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius But unfortunately I can't apply the solution from the link you posted to my problem - or at least I don't see how.

Comment: @nyronium Why can't you write overloaded operators for `SomeEnum` class? That's essentially what `Flags` enum is in the linked question, compared to yours. Differing names != differing problem.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I can't overload any operators for `SomeEnum` as the Flags class should be working for any enum. Its part of a library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to know that `SomeEnum` is convertible to `Flags<SomeEnum>` it would already have to have deduced the `Enum` template argument as `SomeEnum`, but it can't deduce that from the arguments because neither of them matches `Flags<Enum>`.

i.e. the template argument deduction has to happen before conversions to another type can be checked.

You can adjust the functions so that only one argument participates in argument deduction:

```
template<typename T> struct nondeduced { using type = T; }

template<typename Enum>
Flags<Enum> operator |(Enum a, Flags<typename nondeduced<Enum>::type> b)
```

or equivalently:

```
template<typename E> struct FlagType { using type = Flags<E>; }

template<typename Enum>
Flags<Enum> operator |(Enum a, typename FlagType<Enum>::type b);
```

This uses the `Enum` template argument in a non-deduced context, so only the other argument is used for deduction.

But after doing that you now have ambiguous overloads, because there's no way for the compiler to know whether you want the first argument to be converted, or the second argument.

You need to add an overload that takes two `SomeEnum` types, and performs the conversions to `Flags<SomeEnum>` explicitly. If an enumeration type is supposed to be used with `operator|` then it should define that operator itself.

Another option that doesn't involve changing the enumeration types would be to add a helper that turns an enumerator into a `Flags` object:

```
template<typename Enum>
inline Flags<Enum> flags(Enum e) { return Flags<Enum>(e); }
```

then you can say `SomeEnum::TWO | flags(SomeEnum::TWO)` which avoids the ambiguity.

As a stylistic point, [don't use ALL_CAPS for enumerators](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1923).

Comment: Is there a way to prioritize one of the ambiguous overloads? Because `Flags` is part of a library I now have to create `template<typename Enum> operator |(Enum a, Enum b)` which might break other enums which are should not be used for Flags.

Comment: @nyronium that sounds like a recipe for disaster to me, having `a | b` do something different based on a subtle context change

Comment: @M.M well probably... Though it isn't a theoretical problem, just a c++ one. Maybe one day.

Comment: @M.M Actually, if I apply this solution to only one of the two operators, I would have exactly this behavior. If a user defined operator Enum | Enum exists, it takes precedence and there is no ambiguity in any case.

Comment: @jonathan-wakely, would you mind elaborating on this approach for completeness?

Comment: What is "this solution" and "this approach" referring to? I didn't say to add a templated `operator|` but to add a (non-template) `operator|(SomeEnum, SomeEnum)`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Sorry for being imprecise. I was talking about applying your `Flags<typename nondeduced<Enum>::type>` to only one of the two global operators. Then there is no ambiguity and no need for `operator|(SomeEnum, SomeEnum)`. If the user then defines such an operator, it will even take precedence which is perfect.

Comment: This answer would be improved by mentioning the ADL/Koenig lookup problem and which namespace this tooling has to be in (the `Enum` namespace)